# Relationship between the dual of a subspace and its annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. I shall use the following notation: $V^*$ will be the dual space of $V$, $Wº$ will be the annihilator of $W$, that is the set of linear forms that annihilate every vector in $W$. Finally, $W^*$ will be the dual of the subspace $W$.

I am asked to prove the relationship:

$$ W^* \oplus Wº = V^* $$

Now, my approach initially would be to take a basis of $W$ and extend it to a basis of $V$. Then the corresponding linear forms in $V^*$ of the former set of vectors will correspond to the dual of $W$ and the rest will be a basis for the annihilator.

However, I was told I should be using an exact sequence of the following type:

$$ 0 \rightarrow W \xrightarrow{i} V \xrightarrow{\pi} \frac{V}{W} \rightarrow 0$$

Here, $i$ denotes the natural inclusion, $\pi$ denotes the quotient map to the quotient space $V$ by $W$. Now, since this sequence is exact, the corresponding sequence in duals will also be exact, that is:

$$ 0 \rightarrow (\frac{V}{W})^* \xrightarrow{\pi^*} V^* \xrightarrow{i^*} W^* \rightarrow 0 $$

Now since this sequence is also an exact sequence, we have that $i^*$ is surjective, $\pi^*$ is injective and:

$$ \text{Im}(\pi^*)  = \text{Ker}(i^*)$$
Now, how could one use this relationship to prove that the annihilator of $W$ is supplementary to its dual? This question seemed rather odd since I have never seen an explicit definition of the dual of a subspace, but have rather been told that it defined by the above exact sequence and is *not* a subspace of the dual, but instead is equal to some quotient that can be seen, again, with the sequence above. So, how does one define the dual of a space with this sequence, and with that, prove the relation above?

Comment: "Now, my approach initially would be to take a basis of $W$ and extend it to a basis of $V$. Then the corresponding linear forms in $V^*$ of the former set of vectors will correspond to the dual of $W$ and the rest will be a basis for the annihilator." That should work just fine. 
"I was told I should be using an exact sequence" This to me sounds like they want to introduce the concept of exact sequences to you. I would say that just taking a basis is easier than taking exact sequences. (For one, because then the inclusion $W^*\hookrightarrow V^*$ is uniquely defined).

Comment: @student91 the problem with that is that I need the exact explicit relationship between the vectors in the space and the linear forms in the dual, so that would not be "formal enough". On top of that, I have been told, as I said, that $W^*$ is not a subspace of $V^*$ and that it is a subspace of some quotient or the quotient of a dual they expect us to find. That is why the exact sequence is necessary

Comment: Then you should dualize the identity $V \cong W\oplus V/W$. (Note: I have $V/W$ instead of $W/V$, because $W\subseteq V$. Similarly, I can only do $W^*/V^*$ because $V^*\subseteq W^*$). You should obtain $V^*\cong W^*\oplus W^*/V^*$. Hint: We have that $\dim(\mathrm{image}(\pi)) + \dim(\ker(\pi)) =  \dim V$, and $\ker(\pi)=W$.

Comment: You should be looking for a relationship between $W^*$ and $V^*/W^0$.

Comment: @blargoner thinking about their dimensions, I can see that they are isomorphic. The thing is, I don't know if they are equal or not since I don't have a clear idea of what the elements of $W^*$ are. I was told it was not a subspace of the dual of $V$, but how can I see what its elements "are" and wether or not they are classes of equivalence belonging to the quotient space (or the dual of a quotient space)?

Comment: @Nick.25 They are not strictly equal, but equality is not important. They are naturally isomorphic. For a linear form on $V$, its restriction to $W$ is a linear form on $W$. This gives a linear map $V^*\to W^*$. What is the image? What is the kernel? What does that tell you?

Comment: @blargoner I see the Image is $W^*$ and the Kernel is $W^0$, hence the isomorphism. Also, this means that every form in $W^0$ will be mapped to zero, so that the natural isomorphism between those two is simply taking the equivalence class of the dual by the annihilator. Is seeing that natural inclusion enough to prove the statement? I mean, taking a basis of $W$ and extending it to $V$ it seems that the first vectors will me mapped to the dual basis of $W^*$ while the rest will be a basis for $W^0$.

Comment: @blargoner I do see that this natural isomorphism directly implies the direct sum, but making it explicit formally seems rather off, since one would be taking the sum of a quotient space (due to the natural isomorphism) and a proper subspace of $V^0$

Comment: @Nick.25 I was suggesting forgetting about the relationship you were asked to prove because as written it is false. The natural iso is the right relationship.